# Codeblocks why is my code unable to open my .csv file

Tags: file, codeblocks

This is part of my code, of course I have `#include fstream>`, and to basically run you throught what the code should do at this point is open a file I have name `"flights.csv"` and in a function called `readFlights` count how many flights are in the file and then return the size, but when ran it returns a size of 0 when there are 5 in the file, and gives me my error file open message.

```
int main()
{
ifstream in("flights.csv");
if(!in.is_open()) cout << "ERROR: File open" << endl;
Flights flightsList[100];
const int SIZE = readFlights(in, flightsList);
cout << "Size: " << SIZE <<endl;
```

here is the function for counting the size and putting it into an array.

```
int readFlights(ifstream& in, Flights flightsList[100]){
//Reads the file flights.csv and returns a size used for array.
string pdStore, dmStore;
int size= 0;
while(in.good()){
    getline(in, flightsList[size].fromCity,',');
    getline(in, flightsList[size].toCity,',');
    getline(in, pdStore,',');
    flightsList[size].priceDollars = stoi(pdStore);
    getline(in, dmStore,'\n');
    flightsList[size].distanceMiles = stoi(dmStore);
    size++;
}
return size;
}
```

I thought it was interesting but I don't know if this is necessary but inside code blocks the `.csv` part of the file in `ifstream in("flights.csv");` was underlined with the red jagged lines.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had no clue I had to include the file into the project folder itself...